# C3js: How to move and rotate grid line text?

Tags: css, c3.js

It is possible to add grid lines to a C3js chart, as shown on the following pages:

[Add x grid lines](https://c3js.org/samples/grid_x_lines.html)

[Style x grid lines](https://c3js.org/samples/style_grid.html)

The second link above shows how to style the grid lines.

How would one, using CSS or another method:

(a) move the grid line text to the other side of the grid line?

(b) rotate the text clockwise 90 degrees, and move it left, right, etc?

UPDATE: I am using `React-c3js`, so I cannot simply select an SVG element and transform and rotate it (hence the suggestion to use `CSS`).

Comment: I'm no expert but a quick search through the source of c3/grid.js for the string 'rotat' shows references only to a var named 'axis_rotated'. I assume from this that all the code referencing this attribute is focussed on axis rotation and no text rotation of individual grid line text elements.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat. Yes, I also was unable to find options for moving the text around. My only hope, if any, is through CSS. The selector `.c3-xgrid-line text` applies to this text.

Comment: ok - so you are prepared to accept a JS solution I guess. A little investigation leads me to think that we need to handle rotation (easy) but also handle the rotation point. Should be doable though.

Comment: Does react-c3.js not have the onrendered() event ? This fires after the chart is rendered for the first time. Reason I ask is that to re-rotate the text you will need to  calculate and transform the rotation origin then apply rotation. I do not think the calculations needed are well-supported or even possible in fixed css. The onrendered() option would allow use of DOM manipulation in procedural JS which would have a far better chance of success and cross-browser operation.

Comment: I would upvote this question more times if I could, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. The onrendered() event of the chart is used to run some JS that uses d3.js (already present as you are using c3.js) to target the grid-line text and manipulate it as required. See the red text 'Label 2' and 'LABEL4'.

I did reasonable research on a CSS solution but my conclusion is that the CSS approach will be problematic as the interface between CSS and SVG attributes is inconsistent at time of writing. The JS solution seems viable.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const columns = [
  ['My Numbers', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
  ['Your Numbers', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
];

class Chart extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._updateChart();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._updateChart();
  }
  _updateChart() {
    const chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      size: { width: 400, height: 200},
      data: {
        columns: this.props.columns,
        type: this.props.chartType
      },
          grid: {
        x: {
            lines: [{value: 2, text: 'Label 2'}, {value: 4, text: 'LABEL 4'}]
        },
        y: {
            lines: [{value: 300, text: 'LABEL 300'}]
        }
    },
      onrendered:  function() {

        // for each svg element with the class 'c3-xgrid-line'
        d3.selectAll('.c3-xgrid-line').each(function(d, i){

          // cache the group node
          var groupNode = d3.select(this).node();         

          // for each 'text' element within the group 
          d3.select(this).select('text').each(function(d, i){
                        
            // hide the text to get size of group box otherwise text affects size.
            d3.select(this).attr("hidden",true); 

            // use svg getBBox() func to get the group size without the text - want the position
            var groupBx = groupNode.getBBox();

            d3.select(this)
              .attr('transform', null) // remove text rotation
              .attr('x', groupBx.x)   // x-offset from left of chart
              .attr('y', 0)          // y-offset of the text from the top of the chart 
              .attr('dx', 20)         // small x-adjust to clear the line
              .attr('dy', 15)         // small y-adjust to get onto the chart
              .attr("hidden", null)   // better make the text visible again
              .attr("text-anchor", null)  // anchor to left by default
              .style('fill', 'red');    // color it red for fun
            })
        })   
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
 
    
    return <div id="chart">hi</div>;  
    
  }

}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._setBarChart = this._setBarChart.bind(this);
    this._setLineChart = this._setLineChart.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      chartType: 'line'
    };
  }
  _setBarChart() {
    this.setState({ chartType: 'bar' });
  }
  _setLineChart() {
    this.setState({ chartType: 'line' });
  }
 render() {
  return (
      <div className="app-wrap">
        <Chart 
          columns={columns}
          chartType={this.state.chartType} />
        <p>
          Chart Type
          <button onClick={this._setBarChart}>bar</button> 
          <button onClick={this._setLineChart}>Line</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  margin-left: 1em;
  background: #159fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

#chart {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.js"></script>



<div class='chart-wrapper'>
<div id="app"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would upvote this answer more times if I could, thank you for answering.